# gcc -fno-stack-protector is not working, how to fix it?

Tags: c, gcc, overflow

I am trying to mock a C stack overflow using strcpy like this:

```
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    return 0;
}
```

and I try to compile the file using -fno-stack-protector to avoid compile errors:

```
$ gcc -ggdb -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -fno-stack-protector -o overflow overflow.c
```

but I failed and got this error:

```
overflow.c: In function ‘main’:
overflow.c:4:2: warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 36 bytes into a region of size 10 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
    4 |  strcpy(str, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is the gcc version output for reference:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-9QDOt0/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
```

Why is the "-fno-stack-protector" option not working?
I want the code compiling without any errors.

I will be so happy if anyone could help me out of here.

Love and respect to you.

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error.

Comment: Stack protector is a mechanism to detect stack overflows in the runtime. By disabling it you are not automatically gaining the right to write buggy programs, you are merely disabling that mechanism. And the compiler is still trying to warn you that your code is buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warning from the compiler because it detects the overflow at compile time. Stack protector operates when you run the program. To suppress the warning use the [`-Wno-stringop-overflow`](https://-Wno-stringop-overflow) compilation option.